# Как зациклить видео при помощи js?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть видео которое я пытаюсь зациклить чтоб оно воспроизводилось сначала. Слушаю события `"ended"` и потом задаю время `currentTime` и воспроизвожу.

Но проблема в том, что каждый новый цикл видео буферизируется заново.

Как-то можно сделать то же самое, но чтоб видео буферизировалось единожды, а потом все время играло?

Comment: А чем атрибут `loop` не подходит?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Атрибут loop](http://htmlbook.ru/html/video/loop) - Зацикливает воспроизведение видео, оно повторяется каждый раз с начала после завершения.

> Синтаксис
>
> ```
> <video loop="loop">
> </video>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var v = $(".video-stream");
v.addEventListener('timeupdate', function() {
   if (Math.round(v.currentTime) == 100) v.currentTime = 15;
});
# первая цифра (в примере 100) - конец отрезка в секундах,
# вторая (15) - начало (куда прыгнуть)
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]